# Use a contents of a variable to make a range of variable name.

Tags: r

I have set up a script to take user inputs. I want to use one of the inputs to be used to initialize a range of variables.

`X <- 'a' # a is what the user would input from command line`

I want to add the contents of `X` to a range of variable names. I want the final names to look like:

`XXX_a_1 <- #something;`
`XXX_a_2 <- #something;`
`XXX_a_3 <- #something;`
`XXX_a_4 <- #something;`
`XXX_a_5 <- #something;`
`XXX_a_6 <- #something;`

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Why don't you just use a vector or a list?

Comment: How would I include the user input in the list/vector?

Comment: This is FAQ 7.21 (combined with the `paste` or `sprintf` function).  The most important part of that FAQ is the last bit where it suggests using a list instead as @nico shows in his answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not clear what do you want to do with separated variables. It is better to work with a list or an environment. For example, you can create a named list like this :

```
X <- 'a'
L <- vector("list", 5)
names(L) <- paste('XXX',X,1:5,sep='_')
```

Of course, you can convert your list to separate variables using `list2env` :

```
list2env(L,.GlobalEnv)
ls(pattern='XXX')
[1] "XXX_a_1" "XXX_a_2" "XXX_a_3" "XXX_a_4" "XXX_a_5"
```

Answer (score 3):

R is optimised to deal with vectors and lists, so in general when you find yourself creating lots of variable you should ask yourself whether a vector/list would be better to use.

You could do, for instance:

```
user.input <- "test"
vars <- paste(user.input, 1:5, sep="_")

my.list <- list()

for (v in vars)
  my.list[[v]] = sample(1:10, 1)
```

Which gives:

```
> my.list
$test_1
[1] 3

$test_2
[1] 5

$test_3
[1] 3

$test_4
[1] 5

$test_5
[1] 5
```

Comment: Thanks. The individual variables carry lists themselves and are called by different functions at different sections in the code. It was not east to manage to a list of lists, so I wanted to create individual variables. I probably should have read the FAQ thoroughly.

Answer (score 2):

Probably want to use paste (or paste0) to create the variable name, and then use assign to give a variable with that name your values:

```
X <- "a"
assign(paste0("XXX_",X,"_1"), "value1")
print(XXX_a_1)
```

If you give more information, I can help with the loops of assigning these values.